# In scala, how to pattern match against an inlined expression?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

In scala, a pattern matching for a class has to be conducted in the following way:

```
    val clz: Class[_] = ???

    clz match {
      case v if clz == classOf[String] =>
        // do something
      case v if clz == classOf[Int] =>
        // do something
      //...
    }
```

The boilerplate code `v if clz ==` is really redundant and I'd like to have them removed or reduced, since functions like `classOf[String]` and `classOf[int]` can be inlined and used like constant. So how can I do this?

Comment: You shouldn't be checking about classes this way. Probably there are better ways to model your problem. - Anyways, answering your specific question, this is the minimal way to do this AFAIK.

Comment: Why not to use `if-else-if`s?

Answer (score 2):

There is some support, mostly in relation to array element types:

```
scala> import reflect.ClassTag
import reflect.ClassTag

scala> val c: Class[_] = classOf[Int]
c: Class[_] = int

scala> (ClassTag(c): Any) match { case ClassTag.Boolean => "bool" case ClassTag.Int => "int" }
res0: String = int
```

but the use case is to simplify type tests

```
scala> def f[A: ClassTag] = ("abc": Any) match { case _: A => "A" case _ => "other" }
f: [A](implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[A])String

scala> f[Int]
res1: String = other

scala> f[String]
res2: String = A
```

Maybe one argument for `classTag` not looking like a stable id is that `classOf[C]` evaluated in different classloaders don't compare equal.